# How to get a simple JSON out of a MongoDb-Document (Java)

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I work with MongoDb and Jersey in Java. I like to return the Documents I read out of the DB directly as JSON to my AngularJS client. If I call toJson() on a Document I get this BSON representation. That means that a Long for example is represented as an object with a key-value-pair "$numberLong". I don't like this type information in my JSON.

Is there any way to get a simple JSON out of this Document, without converting it to a Java-Object and back? What are the best practices to work with this Documents? Would you include that type information?